# fastai tabular dataloader with parquet files

Tags: fast-ai

How can I train a tabular model with fast.ai using a [TabularDataLoader](https://docs.fast.ai/tabular.data.html#tabulardataloaders) from a folder of Parquet files?  The current methods only seem to support pandas dataframes and CSV files?